# How do i fix #prettyPhoto[gallery_recent_1]/0/ from URL

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I am working on a website http://www.uspoolbuilder.com/gallery-1

when i click on any image then URL is getting change like that

> http://www.uspoolbuilder.com/gallery-1/#prettyPhoto[gallery_recent_1]/0/

How do i stop this URL change

Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add deeplinking: false .. it will solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `deeplinking: false` when you initialize prettyPhoto.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Comment: There is no change when i use deeplinking: false . check on this image www.uspoolbuilder.com/contact